# Rails simple_form creates empty item in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm creating a form to add comments, right before my comment box. Sadly, it seems that this form creates an empty object in the collection which is shown in the comments without content. How do I prevent this?

```
.comments
      = simple_form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f|
        = f.input :content, label: "Comment"
        = f.button :submit

      - @post.comments.each do |c|
        p = c.content
        p = c.user.profile.full_name unless c.user.nil? || c.user.profile.nil?

# comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_commentable

  def index
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment."
      redirect_to @commentable
    else
      redirect_to @commentable
    end
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end

    def find_commentable
      params.each do |name, value|
        if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
          return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
        end
      end
      nil
    end
end
```

Comment: show your controller method and comment_params method

Comment: Really doubt it is going to help but I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to not display non-persisted records. You can do this like this:

```
- @post.comments.each do |c|
  - next unless c.persisted?
  ...
```

or:

```
- @post.comments.find_all(&:persisted?).each do |c|
  ...
```

Comment: When you call `@post.comments`, that's a database lookup. So all the records will be guaranteed to be persisted.

Comment: `@post.comments` returns an association object, which can contain non-persisted records if you call `@post.comments.build` before iterating over it.